# constructor with std::pair as argument: T a({1,2}) works, T a = {1,2} doesn't

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, assignment-operator, std-pair

I needed big integers for a combinatorics algorithm I'm working on, and as an exercise I thought I'd write a simple 128-bit integer class, but I'm running into some inconsistencies with the constructors.

I have several constructors, so that you can create a `uint128_t` from another one (with the implicit copy constructor) or from a 64-bit integer or from a pair of 64-bit integers. This all works, but what's confusing me is that I can use this syntax:

```cpp
uint128_t a = 123ull;
uint128_t b = a;
```

but not:

```cpp
uint128_t e = {123ull, 456ull};               // COMPILER ERROR
uint128_t f = std::make_pair(123ull, 456ull); // COMPILER ERROR
```

even though these work:

```cpp
uint128_t c({123ull, 456ull});
uint128_t d(std::make_pair(123ull, 456ull));
```

The errors I'm getting are:

```
could not convert '{123, 345}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'uint128_t'
conversion from 'std::pair<long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int>' to non-scalar type 'uint128_t' requested
```

I could just use the syntax that works, but I'm wondering whether there's something simple I'm missing that would get the `uint128_t a = {1,2}` syntax to work, because that would make it easier to convert existing code to work with 128-bit integers.

Here is an overview of what works and what doesn't, and the relevant parts of the class:

```cpp
#include "uint128_t.hpp"

int main() {
    uint128_t a = 123ull;               // explixit constructor from uint64_t = ok
    uint128_t b = a;                    // implicit copy constructor = ok
    a = b;                              // assignment from uint128_t = ok
    b = 123ull;                         // assignment from uint64_t = ok
    a = {123ull, 456ull};               // assignment from pair of uint64_t = ok
    b = std::make_pair(123ull, 456ull); // assignment from pair of uint64_t = ok
    uint128_t c({123ull, 456ull});      // explixit constructor from pair = ok
    uint128_t d(std::make_pair(123ull, 456ull));

    uint128_t e = {123ull, 456ull};               // COMPILER ERROR
    uint128_t f = std::make_pair(123ull, 456ull); // COMPILER ERROR

    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

class uint128_t {
    private:

    uint64_t hi;
    uint64_t lo;

    public:

    uint128_t() {}
   ~uint128_t() {}
    uint128_t(uint64_t const& val) {
        hi = UINT64_C(0);
        lo = val;
    }
    uint128_t(std::pair<uint64_t const, uint64_t const> const& val) {
        hi = val.first;
        lo = val.second;
    }
    uint128_t const& operator=(uint128_t const&);
    uint128_t const& operator=(uint64_t const);
    uint128_t const& operator=(std::pair<uint64_t const, uint64_t const> const&);
}
```

```cpp
#include "uint128_t.hpp"

uint128_t const& uint128_t::operator=(uint128_t  const& other) {
    this->hi = other.hi;
    this->lo = other.lo;
    return *this;
}

uint128_t const& uint128_t::operator=(uint64_t const val) {
    this->hi = UINT64_C(0);
    this->lo = val;
    return *this;
}

uint128_t const& uint128_t::operator=(std::pair<uint64_t const, uint64_t const> const& val) {
    this->hi = val.first;
    this->lo = val.second;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: `uint128_t::uint128_t(uint64_t, uint64_t)`

Comment: Why do you keep referring to `ull` literals as `uint64_t`? The second error is actually caused by that. Your literals are *not* `uint64_t`. And the compiler cannot convert `std::pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long>` to your `std::pair<uint64_t const, uint64_t const>` because that would be the *second* implicit user-defined conversion in a context where only *one* such conversion is allowed.

Comment: @AnT Removing `ull` or replacing it by a cast to uint64_t doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @m69: That's because you also have that bizarre `const` in template parameters, which still forces the second conversion. If you simply add casts to your code, your `std::make_pair` will generate `std::pair<uint64_t, uint64_t>`, but your constructor wants `std::pair<const uint64_t, const uint64_t>`. These are two different types, which triggers another user defined conversion. Get rid of that `const` as well. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb92e1103369b38c

Comment: Simply removing `ull` will not help, since it preserves the same problem.

Comment: @AnT Thank you. Getting rig of the obsolete consts's and adding casts has indeed got the `make_pair` version working. (Oddly, the shorthand {123,456} for a pair seems to work with `a({123,456})` but not with `a = {123,456}`.)

Comment: @m69: It will work with `a({123,456})`, but wont work with `a = {123,456}` or `a{123,456}`. The latter two are *list-initializations*, while `a({123,456})` is a direct-initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first copy-initialization

```
uint128_t e = {123ull, 456ull};
```

you are using a multi-valued list to initialize a non-aggregate class. In accordance with the rules of *list-initialization*, in such cases the compiler will consider `std::initializer_list` constructors and then it will consider two-parameter constructors in your class. No matching constructor exists in your class, so the initialization fails.

You probably expected the compiler to convert the `{123ull, 456ull}` to `std::pair` and then use that `std::pair` to initialize `e`. But list-initialization in C++ does not consider this initialization path. (Note, BTW, that this would also look like a sequence of two user-defined conversions, see below.)

Your second copy-initialization

```
uint128_t f = std::make_pair(123ull, 456ull);
```

fails for the same reason the following simplified code fails

```
struct A { A(int) {} };
struct B { B(const A &) {} };

int main() {
  B b1(42);  // OK
  B b2 = 42; // Error
}
```

The above copy-initialization requires *two* implicit user-defined conversions in its conversion sequence: from `int` to `A` and then from `A` to `B`. Even though such conversions exist, implicitly applying two of them is not allowed. At most one implicit user-defined conversion is allowed in copy-initialization.

In your case you are requesting conversion from `std::pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long>` to `std::pair<uint64_t const, uint64_t const>` (constructor parameter type) and then from `std::pair<uint64_t const, uint64_t const>` to `uint128_t` - two conversions. These conversions exist, but two in a row is too many.

Even if you make sure that arguments of `std::make_pair` have `uint64_t` type, those `const` qualifiers in `std::pair<uint64_t const, uint64_t const>` will still force the extra conversion. Your `make_pair` call will produce an `std::pair<uint64_t, uint64_t>` value which has to be converted to `std::pair<uint64_t const, uint64_t const>` and then converted to `uint128_t`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the correspond constructors

---

```
uint128_t::uint128_t(uint64_t, uint64_t) //uint128_t x = {123ull, 456ull};
uint128_t::uint128_t(const std::pair<uint64_t,uint64_t>& val) //uint128_t x = std::make_pair(123ull, 456ull);*
```

---

notice that `ull` would not always equal to `uint64_t`

Comment: Thanks. I'd used the std::pair for the assignment operator, and carried over that logic to the constructors unnecessarily.

Comment: the `std::pair`s, IMHO, is unnecessary at all, though.